# vba Open excel when File is used by another user

Tags: excel, vba

This is my current code

```
Public Sub OpenFiles()
    'Set LiveDealSheet file path
    'Check if LiveDealSheet is already open
    LDSP = "C:\Users\DCHEUNG\Desktop\Programing\LiveDealSheet.xlsm"
    IsOTF = IsWorkBookOpen(LDSP)

    'Set quick workbook shortcut
    Set TWB = ThisWorkbook
    If IsOTF = False Then
        Set LDS = Workbooks.Open(LDSP)
    Else
        Workbooks("LiveDealSheet.xlsm").Activate
        Set LDS = ActiveWorkbook
    End If
End Sub

Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
'i was just browsing through the online library and I found that "Open FileName For..." 
'have a lot of keywords. If I only want to open the file and copy stuff out to 
'another workbook do I use "Open FileName for Input Read As #ff"? 
'Then when I actually open the file in OpenFiles() I change 
'"Set LDS = Workbooks.Open(LDSP)" to "Set LDS = Workbooks.Open(LDSP) (ReadOnly)"
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

The file I am trying to open is a shared file. When no is it using, or when I already opened the file, this code works fine. But whenever another user already open a file, this code stops.

I know for a fact that even if another use is using the file, I can still open it in Read-Only mode. So my question is how to include that code in here, and hopefully without the pop-up asking if you want to open in Read-Only mode.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I am totally new to coding.

Comment: macros dont work with shared workbook.

Comment: I just uploaded an image please see if you haven't already. Anyway what you see is that I can manually click Read Only if I try to open the workbook without vba. However using vba doesn't even show this popup. cause i don't think there is an error code for this. So what I want to do is if there is a workaround that can open it

Answer (score 4):

First of all thanks for you input. I have solve the problem on my own with some trial and error.

changed the code to the following

```
Public Sub OpenFiles()
    'Set LiveDealSheet file path
    'Check if LiveDealSheet is already open
    LDSP = "Z:\LiveDealSheet.xlsm"
    IsOTF = IsWorkBookOpen(LDSP)

    'Set quick workbook shortcut
    Set TWB = ThisWorkbook
    If IsOTF = False Then
        Set LDS = Workbooks.Open(LDSP)
        Debug.Print "Stage 1 Success"
```

changed everything in this else statement

```
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        Set LDS = Workbooks("LiveDealSheet.xlsm")
        If LDS Is Nothing Then Workbooks.Open FileName:=LDSP, ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True
    End If
End Sub

Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Could you actually explain what you did? If not I'll downvote as sifting through 25 lines of uncommented code is not a good form of an answer.

Comment: Here is the source for IsWorkbookOpen.  Has good code comments.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291295

Answer (score 0):

I would replace all the scripted above with this:

```
Public Sub OpenFiles()
        On Error GoTo not_open
        Workbooks("C:\Users\DCHEUNG\Desktop\Programing\LiveDealSheet.xlsm").Activate
        Exit Sub
        not_open:
        Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\Users\DCHEUNG\Desktop\Programing\LiveDealSheet.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True
        Err.Clear
        Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What if the workbook was originally open by no one?  Then, this code would unnecessarily open the workbook read-only when it could have been opened normally (i.e. writable).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was helped somewhat by the existing posts, here. However, there was still a gap between the recommendations and reality. So, I'll try to share my lessons learned.

In my case, I needed Workbooks.Open to open the most recent file in a shared folder. This file is often referenced by other users and is therefore frequently open by other users. Below is my first pass to give the VBA code "permission" to open the file as "read only."

```
' OPEN SOURCE-FILE IN READ-ONLY MODE (argument key below)
Workbooks.Open _
    Filename:=strFilename, _
    UpdateLinks:=0, _
    ReadOnly:=True, _
    IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, _
    Notify:=True
```

This actually works EXCEPT for when excel creates a temporary file in the source folder (the temp file will, therefore, always be the newest file in the folder). To handle that exception, I needed to truncate the temp characters: "~$". I have done that with

```
Right([your_string], integer_length_of_string)
```

See in context below.

```
For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
    If InStr(1, objFile.Name, ".xlsm") And objFile.DateLastModified > dateFile Then
        dateFile = objFile.DateLastModified
        windowName = objFile.Name

            If InStr(1, windowName, "~$") Then
                fileNameLen = Len(objFile.Name) - 2
                windowName = Right(objFile.Name, fileNameLen)
                strFilename = myDir & "\" & windowName
            End If

        strFilename = myDir & "\" & windowName
    End If
Next objFile
```