# Replace Worksheets content without opening it

Tags: excel, vba, ado

I am using ADO model to gather data from various closes workbooks. This is working well.

I now want to put this data in another closed workbook, but I would like to be able to delete a sheet content before.

**How can I delete a worksheet content without opening the workbook using VBA ?**

**How can I transfer a record set to a closed wb ? / Copy one table to another using ADO ?**

EDIT :

I was able to insert some data from one workbook to another one in a new sheet but I can't get to output data in an existing worksheet.

When I try the INSERT INTO statement, an error is raised. Update impossible, database or object readonly.

Here is the code :

```
Sub tranfert()

    Dim ExcelCn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim ExcelRst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim Rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim maBase As String, maFeuille As String
    Dim maTable As String, NomClasseur As String
    Dim nbEnr As Long

    maBase = "C:\Users\Lichar\Documents\Base.xlsx"
    maTable = "[table$]"
    NomClasseur = "C:\Users\Lichar\Documents\Target.xlsx"
    maFeuille = "Sheet2"


    'Connection to base file
    Cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                   "Data Source=" & maBase & ";" & _
                   "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;"""
    'Requète dans la table Access
    Rst.Open "SELECT * FROM " & maTable, Cn

    'Connection to target file
    Set ExcelCn = New ADODB.Connection
    ExcelCn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                   "Data Source=" & NomClasseur & ";" & _
                   "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;"""

    '-----------------------------------------
    'Create a new sheet and output data
    Cn.Execute "SELECT * INTO [Excel 12.0;" & _
        "Database=" & NomClasseur & "].[" & maFeuille & "] FROM " & maTable, nbEnr

    '-----------------------------------------
    'Trying to ouput data in existing sheet
    'Cn.Execute "INSERT INTO [sheet$] IN '' [Excel 12.0;" & _
    '    "Database='" & NomClasseur & "'] SELECT * FROM " & maTable, nbEnr


    Rst.Close
    Cn.Close
    Set ExcelRst = Nothing
    Set ExcelCn = Nothing
```

**EDIT 2 **

I've found a *partial solution* using INSERT INTO. Here is a working code that takes data from source.xlsx in the table sheet and output it (or append) in target.xlsx in the sheet sheet :

```
Sub SQLQUERY()
    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim QUERY_SQL As String
    Dim Rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ExcelCn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim ExcelRst As ADODB.Recordset

    SourcePath = "C:\Users\BVR\Documents\Source.xlsx"
    TargetPath = "C:\Users\BVR\Documents\Target.xlsx"

    CHAINE_HDR = "[Excel 12.0 MACRO;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'] "


    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection

    STRCONNECTION = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source='" & SourcePath & "';" & _
    "Mode=Read;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;"";"


    QUERY_SQL = _
    "SELECT * FROM [table$] "


    Cn.Open STRCONNECTION

    Set ExcelCn = New ADODB.Connection
    ExcelCn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                   "Data Source=" & TargetPath & ";" & _
                   "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;"""

    Cn.Execute "INSERT INTO [sheet$] IN '" & TargetPath & "' 'Excel 12.0;' " & QUERY_SQL


    '--- Fermeture connexion ---
    Cn.Close

End Sub
```

I've noticed 2 problems. First If one of my field name contains a "." in it, the code will generate an error stating that INSERT INTO contains an unknown field name. This is problematic.
Second I cannot select only the columns I want. If I "SELECT [F1], [F2] ..." an error will raise stating that there is a circular reference. (I can however select the columns I want using field names)

Comment: This kind of questions has been asked many times before and thus far I haven't seen any answer which is able to **write** to a file without opening it. Just to clarify: by "opening it" I do not necessarily mean "visually open it" but at least putting a lock on the file.

Comment: I know this is possible. Here you have an example of transfer from an access database to a spreadsheet. I want to do the same thing but with a worksheet as the source. http://silkyroad.developpez.com/VBA/ClasseursFermes/#LIV-D (French)

Comment: Even though the french introduction (in the link) suggest that the code does not open the Excel file you can see for yourself that there is a `ExcelCn.Open` command in it which passes `NomClasseur` (or the Excel file name) as a connection string and thus opens the file (in the sense that a lock is put on the file). So, here you have the case that data is written to an (existing) file without Excel showing you the opening-process. Still a lock is put on the file while opening it (in the background) to write into the file. At the end of the code the file is closed using `Set ExcelCn = Nothing`.

Comment: I do understand your point now. The same process occurs when I'm taking data from closed workbooks then ? To me it looks like ExcelCn.Open open a connection to the file, not the file itself which makes a big difference. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Now, it is getting kind of technical. But without getting into too much details I can say that much: Excel / Windows can open a file without locking it if it is for "read only". Here is such an example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25913111/1153513. Basically, what Excel does is that it opens the latest available copy of that file (as written to disk) and shows it to you (for read only). Of course, this copy will not include the data the other person is currently adding / editing and has not yet written to disk. Only, once the other person is saving to disk you can grab these changes.

Comment: Thanks. Now let's say this method, while "opening the file", is good for my purposes, how can I use the french link I provided you to write into an excel sheet table. He takes data from Access and report it to Excel. I wanna do the exact same thing but taking another excel worksheets as the source. I tried the first method but I get an error stating that "Worksheets is full" while there is nothing in the target sheet. I also managed to print out the field names but no content (using the 2nd method) ^^

Comment: For editing (on the other hand) you always have to have exclusive access to the file and thus Windows will put a lock on the file. When people start realizing that, that's when they normally start considering the usage of a database server instead. Using an `.mdb` file and MS Access can only be an intermediary solution as Access will merely try to mimic a DB server and you will soon run into troubles with this solution as well. For more information you might be interested in this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#In_Microsoft_Windows

Comment: If that code / solution is good enough for you then you can exchange the line `ExcelCn.Execute "create table " & maFeuille & "(" & listeTable & ")"` for `ExcelCn.Execute "delete * from [YourTableName$]"` to delete all records / rows from a certain table / sheet. Yet, you can only delete rows from that sheet. To delete the entire sheet / table from the underlying Excel file you'll have to open it.

Comment: Thanks. And If I want to use a record set obtained from a closed wb using the same method to input in the same file in which I've deleted all records ? I'm gonna update the question.

Comment: In that case you can iterate through the recordset to generate and SQL INSERT query as shown in this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743347/faster-way-to-import-excel-spreadsheet-to-array-with-ado/30346959#30346959 Afterwards you can pass the query to ADO to insert the records into the Excel file (using your above code snippet again). Note that the actual limit in VBA for strings is 2GB. So, no worries there.

Comment: I can't use .Copyfromrecordset as this supposed the target workbook was opened by excel app. The reason why I'm trying to do this is to handle lot of data, update some target files using some source files without opening any of them.

Comment: That's correct. You cannot use `.CopyFromRecordset`. Is that a new question? Why do you want to use that? As mentioned in my last comment you'll have to loop the recordset and concatenate the result in a large string which you can then pass to ADO to write into the output file (same way it is done in the linked you initially posted above).

Comment: If you look at my edit 2 I've found a way that doesn't need to loop through the record set. I'm still running into some troubles though. I think I'm missing something with the HDR parameter.

Comment: The correct SQL syntax would be [INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp). So based on that you might want to teak your `Cn.Execute` line a bit. Keep us posted and let know if you have found a working solution.

Comment: That's what I have and this is working for simple examples. However, the source file has some "." in the field names (Ref.client for example) and this raise an error. Second, I know the source file may evolve and some columns will be added. I want my code to adapt to this situation ie select only the columns I want or take the whole columns even if my target file doesn't have the desired columns that were added in source.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143367/discussion-between-lich4r-and-ralph).